# display selected value in dropdown php after clicking submit button

Tags: php

I need help. I have try a lot of things but still didnt get the solution for it. I want to display back the selected value for dropdown list after the user click the submit button, but everything I tries I only display either the first or last value of the dropdown element. Im using d..while looping to call out the option value for the dropdown list. Here a my code:

```
<p align="center">Class
<select name="class_code" size="1" id="class_code">

<?php
do{?>
  <option value="<?php echo $row_class_code['class_code']?>" $selected><?php echo $row_class_code['class_code']?></option>
<?php
} while ($row_class_code = mysql_fetch_assoc($class_code));
$rows = mysql_num_rows($class_code);
if($rows > 0) {
  mysql_data_seek($class_code, 0);
  $row_class_code = mysql_fetch_assoc($class_code);
}?>
</select>

<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Proceed" />
</p>
```

Please, can someone help me.

Comment: Will you please show full code like in this given code i cant see submit button ?

Comment: hi @AnkitDoshi, I have edit the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably when submitting you have the selected value in `$_POST['class_code']` - so add a condition to check and add the `selected` attribute for options that match it:

```
<select name="class_code" size="1" id="class_code">
    <?php
    do {
        $selected = (isset($_POST['class_code']) && $row_class_code['class_code'] == $_POST['class_code']);
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row_class_code['class_code']?>"<?php if ($selected) { echo ' selected="selected"'; } ?>><?php echo $row_class_code['class_code']?></option>
        <?php
    } while ($row_class_code = mysql_fetch_assoc($class_code));
    $rows = mysql_num_rows($class_code);
    if ($rows > 0) {
        mysql_data_seek($class_code, 0);
        $row_class_code = mysql_fetch_assoc($class_code);
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate it. It works fine. Thanks a lot

Answer (score -1):

beter you use jquery ajax.

```
$.ajax({
            url: "data.php",//file wich has query select to db table
            data: {id:theid},//describe your data here
            dataType: 'json',// type of data that will you get (JSON/HTML).
            type: 'POST',//sending type (POST/GET)
            success: function(data) {
               showingOption();
            }
        });
```

Then for choose the option which selected you can do this:

```
$("select[name=class_code]>option[value=" + id + "]").attr("selected", "selected");
```

Goodluck for you